# Fail to ping other ports in the loopback connection

Tags: ping, arp, loopback, rhel7

[physical layout]

```
192.168.0.100(eth0)---RJ45----192.168.0.101(eth1)
```

[Execution]

```
# show destination host unreachable.
$ ping -I eth0 192.168.0.101
# no mac address
$ arp -an
```

[Question]

I run `tcpdump -i eth1` and see `arp` package sent to `eth1`.!

Is there any methods to let me able to ping `eth1`?

OS:RHEL7

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static arp entry corresponding to eth1. But I'm not sure I understand your architecture. Are eth0 and eth1 on the same machine ?

Comment: both interfaces on the same machine, and sometimes can ping in one direction. adding arp entry is useless